# Is this following the strategy design pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oop, strategy-pattern

Me and my colleague have a disagreement about if this follows the strategy pattern or not.

We have a react component `List` which expects a "strategy" prop that has the following shape:

```
interface ListStrategy {
  renderItem: (index: number) => React.ReactNode
  itemCount: number
}
```

We have some functions that create a "strategy" for rendering the list in a certain way. For instance we have the following strategy constructors.

```
createGroupedListStrategy(...args: GroupedListStrategyArgs): ListStrategy
createFlatListStrategy(...args: FlatListStrategyArgs): ListStrategy
createTreeListStrategy(...args: TreeListStrategyArgs): ListStrategy
```

I found a lot of examples where the constructor of a strategy either expects no arguments, or expects the same arguments for every strategy. But the constructors above each expect different arguments. `createGroupedListStrategy` expects as an option a function that can be used inside the strategy to match items to their group. `createTreeListStrategy` expects as an option a function that it can use to access the children of an item.

Because the constructors are so different, my colleague started to doubt if these strategies are interchangeable in the sense that the definition of the strategy pattern talks about. But my view is that once the strategies are instantiated, they can be interchanged without a problem.

Can anyone clear this up? I'm really curious.

Comment: The constructors don't matter, the important thing for a strategy is whether it has a uniform interface. Generally, you'd probably have a property like `handler` which is the strategy that could vary. The code would then call something like `handler.doStuff(foo, bar)`. If all your strategies have a `duStuff` method that takes two parameters, that's what you need. The constructors are orthogonal. Ideally, you'd want to produce them from a factory but ultimately, the idea is that the class that has the strategy isn't the one making it. So you decouple an operation from the class.

Comment: Yes, it's still the strategy pattern. It doesn't matter how the strategies are constructed by the caller, it only matters how the chosen strategy is used in the context. (And of course that these are actually different areas in your code, as @VLAZ says).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructors for the strategies don't have any relevance for whether something *is* or *isn't* a strategy. The goal of the strategy pattern is to extract an operation to be independant from the class and to allow you to determine *how* a class behaves, without altering it.

Consider the following, we want to make a trivial "calculator" that takes two values and operates with them. It then displays that result in some way. We want to extract the logic for:

- the calculation - *how* two numbers are handled
- the display - how the result is shown

This would mean that we can change how the calculator works without altering the class itself. So, we extract two strategies:

```typescript
interface CalculationStrategy {
    doMaths: (a: number, b: number) => number
}

interface DisplayStrategy {
    show: (num: number) => void
}
```

And we could supply multiple implementations:

```js
//calculation strategies
class AddStrategy {
  doMaths(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

class MultiplyByConstantStrategy {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  doMaths(a, b) {
    return (a + b) * this.x;
  }
}

//display strategies
class ConsoleDisplayStrategy {
  show(num) {
    console.log(num.toFixed(2))
  }
}

class HTMLDisplayStrategy {
  constructor(elementSelector) {
    this.inputElement = document.querySelector(elementSelector);
  }

  show(num) {
    this.inputElement.value = num;
  }
}

//calculate class
class Calculate {
  constructor(operationHandler, displayHandler) {
    this.operationHandler = operationHandler;
    this.displayHandler = displayHandler;
  }

  calculate(a, b) {
    const result = this.operationHandler.doMaths(a, b);
    this.displayHandler.show(result);
  }
}


/*     usage     */

//calculate the total for a bill + tip
const tip = new Calculate(
  new MultiplyByConstantStrategy(1.15), 
  new HTMLDisplayStrategy("#totalWithTip")
);
document.querySelector("#billTotal")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    const coffee = Number(document.querySelector("#coffeePrice").value);
    const bagel = Number(document.querySelector("#bagelPrice").value);
    
    tip.calculate(coffee, bagel);
  });
  
//just display a calculation on the page
const showAdd = new Calculate(
  new AddStrategy(),
  new HTMLDisplayStrategy("#addResult")
);
showAdd.calculate(2, 8);


//print a sum
const printAdd = new Calculate(
  new AddStrategy(),
  new ConsoleDisplayStrategy()
);

document.querySelector("#printSum")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    const a = Number(document.querySelector("#a").value);
    const b = Number(document.querySelector("#b").value);
    
    printAdd.calculate(a, b);
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    /* prevent the console output from covering the page */
    position: initial !important; 
}
```

```html
<pre>MultiplyByConstantStrategy + HTMLDisplayStrategy</pre>

<div>
  <label for="coffeePrice">Price for coffee:</label>
  <input id="coffeePrice" value="2" type="number" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="bagelPrice">Price for bagel:</label>
  <input id="bagelPrice" value="8" type="number" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="totalWithTip">You owe:</label>
  <input id="totalWithTip" readonly/>
</div>
<button id="billTotal">Bill please!</button>

<hr/>

<pre>AddStrategy + HTMLDisplayStrategy</pre>

<div>
  <label for="addResult">2 + 8 = </label>
  <input id="addResult" readonly/>
</div>

<hr/>

<pre>AddStrategy + ConsoleDisplayStrategy</pre>

<div>
  <input id="a" value="2" type="number" />
  +
  <input id="b" value="8" type="number" />
</div>
<button id="printSum">print the sum</button>
```

The goal is reached here. We've successfully decoupled the calculation and display. We can alter each one without having to change the other or the `Calculate` class. And this is what the strategy pattern tries to solve. The fact that the strategies are constructed with different parameters is irrelevant for this outcome.

Comment: Great answer, I would like to have your opinion. Ive made a sandbox with two examples: 
1. UniversalList
2. SecondUniversalList

In your opinion, do they both meet the strategy criteria or not?
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-archimedes-lmdmt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @MichieldeVos yep, seems fine to me. You have two strategies to choose from and they both have the same interface with `prepareData`. Creating a map of them, then looking them up by name is quite common way of using strategies if you want to alter them dynamically. It also solves the problem of them having different constructors - if you instantiate them, it doesn't matter what parameters are needed for the constructor, you just fetch an already existing object. Note that for your specific example, adaptors might yield better results, as you can apply multiple over the dataset.

Comment: yes, but with SecondUniversalList, we instantiate the strategies where we use them, which creates a coupling and makes them not interchangeable. If we remove the categoryFilter prop, the screen will break. I figured this means SecondUniversalList for this reason doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: @MichieldeVos OK, I missed that. I didn't check the code quite thoroughly. I don't think that really affects them being strategies, however, you probably don't want to instantiate them where you use them. The benefit is reusability and decoupling. You *can* instantiate on the fly but the expectation is that this would happen somewhere else and the object using the strategy will not know nor care which one it is. They might do `lookup[myStrategy]` to get it or get it passed in (like in my example above), or even have some DI produce it from config.