# How could I refactor my JS function to make sure this console.log structure does work?

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I am using this approach to solve this problem but still, my console.log is not returning the expected result, what should I change?

```js
const executeCalculator = ({ x, y, operation }) => {
  let calculator = {
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y,
    operation: {
      "sum": (x, y) => x + y,
      "subtract": (x, y) => x - y,
      "multiply": (x, y) => x * y,
      "divide": (x, y) => x / y,
    },
  }
  if (operation !== 'sum' || 'multiply' || 'subtract' || 'divide') {
    console.error('undefined operation');
  } else {
    return;
  };
};

console.log(executeCalculator({
  operation: 'sum',
  x: 1,
  y: 1
}));
```

Comment: `executeCalculator` does not return anything.

Comment: What are you expecting it to log, and what is it logging instead?

Comment: On a separate note, `x: this.x` will not do anything. The values that you destructure are not on `this`.

Comment: @mplungjan, your suggestion for a working syntax is missing a `!` otherwise it does the opposite of what they are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, your `operation` object was bad formatted, there was an extra comma
- This isn´t necessary:

```
x: this.x,
y: this.y,
```

...since you already have the parameters in your function arguments.

- `"sum": (x, y)`, the x, y parameters aren´t necessary for the same reason.
- Use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if there is a valid operation, make the condition like this:

```
!['sum', 'multiply', 'subtract', 'divide'].includes(operation)
```

- `executeCalculator()` function wasn´t returning anything, you need to return the operation, that´s the reason for the `undefined` result you are getting.

```js
const executeCalculator = ({ x, y, operation }) => {

  let calculator = {
    operation: {
      "sum": () => x + y,
      "subtract": () => x - y,
      "multiply": () => x * y,
      "divide": () => x / y
    }
  }
  if (!['sum', 'multiply', 'subtract', 'divide'].includes(operation)) {
    console.error('undefined operation');
  } else {
    return calculator.operation[operation]();
  };
};

console.log(executeCalculator({
  operation: 'sum',
  x: 1,
  y: 1
}));
```

Comment: It's *much* easier to check for `operation in calculator.operation` to decide whether to execute it. And `calculator.operation` doesn't need to be in `executeCalculator`, either, since it just contains simple functions. If it's extracted and the functions have parameters (like in OP), then the entire body of `executeCalculator` becomes a check if `operation` is valid and then calling `calculator.operation[operation](x, y)`. However, at that point, it's hardly OO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked! Also, I didn't understand the syntax you used here : ```calculator.operation[operation]()```, could you explain it?

Comment: @VivianeMiranda here `calculator.operation[operation]()` what code does is to enter to the `calculator.operation` object, and call the proper operation function. It can also be written as `calculator.operation.sum()` or `calculator.operation.subtract()`, but since you don´t know which would be the operation, you need to call it by the function name as a string using square brackets `[]`.

Comment: *"First of all, your operation object was bad formatted, there was an extra comma"* Trailing commas in object initializers have been valid syntax since [ES5 in 2009](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.1.5).

Comment: @VLAZ Time for you to answer?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure how to answer short of re-writing the entire code. OP asks "what should I change" and I'd personally say "your entire approach from the ground up". Either needs to be something removed from OO and more functional or *actually* OO [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65131392). I don't think I can write an answer that corrects all the mistakes and accurately describes all of this.

Comment: So without OO the body just becomes `return operation in  calculator.operation ? calculator.operation[operation]() : 'invalid operation'`